# Display fields horizontally in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a few lighting-combobox fields that are used as filters.  I want to spread them across the page horizontally.  I was trying to use a  with each filter in a lighting:layoutitem.  I looked at the documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout/example) for LWC layout and it shows there is a horizontal align.  However, when I enter it,

```
<lightning:layout horizontal-align="space">
```

I get an error that its not a valid attribute of lightning:layout.   Any help on how I can get a few lightning-combobox fields spread across the page horizontally would be greatly appreciated! thanks!!

Fred

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example you're looking for is for lightning web components whereas you seem to be writing the code for aura components.

Based on aura's layout component [specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:layout/specification), you need to use the valid attribute:

```
<lightning:layout horizontalAlign="space">
```

Comment: good catch!....

Comment: I see now, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!  The problem was that I was using  lightning:layout when I should have been using lighting-layout.  Thank you!